# highlight or find all words which start with a capital letter

Tags: textmate

How to highlight or find all words which start with a capital letter in textmate?

I have lots of text (around 70 pages) which contains many words which unnecessarily start with a capital letter. I want to inspect all these words and change them to small if needed.
How can I do this in textmate?

any other editor you can suggest?

Im on OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

Use the Find feature (Command-f).  In the top (Find) box, put:

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b
```

Then check the box for Regular Expression and uncheck the box for Ignore case.  Hit OK.  Use Command-g and Command-shift-g to navigate from word to word.